# Module: how to 'unload' the native php?

Tags: php, bash, module

I'm using [modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) to manage which PHP environment I want to load.  However, the machine comes loaded with PHP. This causes a problem because the native php is always used instead of whatever module is loaded.

How can I override this?  I tried prepending the new path to PHP to `$PATH`, but the native php was still used.

On Mac OS X 10.8.2, for reference.

Comment: Which PATH were you updating?  Remember that apache is run under a different username, so you need to change the PATH for that username.

Comment: @AleksG This is actually for command line usage. Maybe I'll integrate apache switching later, but for now its just cli usage.

Comment: In this case, when you're modifying PATH, make sure you put your php path _before_ the system one: `export PATH="/path/to/my/php:$PATH"`

Comment: @AleksG Exactly: hence why I said I tried prepending the new path but it still loads `/usr/bin` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a Mac + PHP version <5.3.16 issue. `make install` would leave the binary as `php.dSYM` instead of the final product. On 5.3.17 this issue has been fixed and everything is working properly.

Odd quirks in darwin.